# Append Jquery page as web component inside a shadow dom

Tags: jquery, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm trying to add a Jquery web app in to an angular app using web components and shadow dom

In order to archive this, I'm using this script

```js
class Legacy2Wc extends HTMLElement {
  url = undefined;
  parent = undefined
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    parent = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' });
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['url'];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (name === 'url' && oldValue !== newValue) {
      this.url = newValue;
      this.render();
    }
  }
  render() {
    const context = this;
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
        context.buildComponent(this.responseText, context);
      }
    });
    xhr.open('GET', this.url);
    xhr.send();
  }
  buildComponent(source, parent) {
    const contextualElement = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(source);
    parent.append(contextualElement);
  }
}
customElements.define('legacy-2-wc', Legacy2Wc);
```

In order to this works properly I add the tag in to the html

```html
<body>
  <legacy-2-wc url="http://some-page-with-jquery.com"></legacy-2-wc>
</body>
```

My target jquery app looks like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="jquery-wc-table">
        <thead>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>address</th>
            <th>date</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/Marak/faker.js/master/examples/browser/js/faker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        faker.seed(1);
        const data = new Array(20).fill({}).map(() => ({
            id: faker.random.uuid(),
            name: faker.name.firstName(),
            address: faker.address.streetAddress(),
            date: faker.date.past()
        }));
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        $(document).ready(() => {
            const filterData = data.filter(dataItem => {
                return !urlParams.has('name') || dataItem.name.toLowerCase().trim().includes(urlParams.get('name').toLowerCase().trim());
            });
            const table = $('#jquery-wc-table tbody');
            table.find('td')
                .remove()
                .end();
            filterData.forEach(dataItem => {
                const row = table.append('<tr></tr>');
                row.append(`<td>${ dataItem.id }</td>`); 
                row.append(`<td>${ dataItem.name }</td>`); 
                row.append(`<td><address>${ dataItem.address }</address></td>`); 
                row.append(`<td>${ dataItem.date.toISOString() }</td>`); 
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open my container app I get errors telling me that jquery is not defined
[image]

It's like the scripts who import jquery aren't do anything or the functionalities of the jquery page have  no access to them

Comment: Would works with mode:open on shadowRoot?

Comment: I tried this already, but not work